# How to calculate this sum : $\sum_ {n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{8^n(3n+1)}$

Tags: calculus

I've found this exercise between those that my Calculus professor gave us the last year, and I realize that I don't know how this sum can be calculated. It was after the part of the course about the function series and the power series, so I tried with the usual techniques but I didn't find anything really useful. The only thing that could be, I think, useful was this formula
$$\sum_ {n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{8^n(3n+1)}=\frac{8}{7}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{3n}{8^n(3n+1)},$$ that I found trying to divide the two factors in the denominator in the following way:
$$\sum_ {n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{8^n(3n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left( \frac{a(n)}{8^n}+\frac{b(n)}{3n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{8^n}-\frac{3n}{(3n+1)8^n}\right).$$
Can you give me some ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is another multisection of series. Start with $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln(1-x)$ and take every third term. Then put $x = 1/2$. Look, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{8^n(3n+1)} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n}}{8^n}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1-\frac{x^3}{8}} = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dz}{1-z^3} $$
and since
$$ \frac{1}{1-z^3} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z}+\frac{2+z}{3(1+z+z^2)} $$
we have:
$$ S = \color{red}{\frac{\log 7}{3}-\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}.$$
An alternative way is to consider that
$$ T(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{2^n(n+1)}=-\frac{2}{x}\log\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right) $$
and that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n}}{8^n(3n+1)} = \frac{T(x)+T(\omega x)+T(\omega^2 x)}{3} $$
with $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since $$\sum_{k\geq0}x^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x},\,\left|x\right|
 $$ we have that $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{3k+1}}{3k+1}=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1-y^{3}}dy
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{y+2}{y^{2}+y+1}dy-\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{y-1}dy
 $$ $$=\dots$$

Comment: @Jacky Chong I don't want to polemicate, but I have seen you have withdrawn your good answer, that you posted maybe after Marco Cantarini, but it is by no means not a copy of his. I just saw your profile which show that you are a very very good contributor. It shouldn't prevent you to contribute to SE. The same thing has happened me some time ago. For Marco Cantarini: I appreciated your comment about series multisection : I didn't know this technique as such (I had used it as a trick without knowing it is a general "boulevard"...).

Comment: I do not understand the downvote here, so (+1) back.